# How to fetch specific user property key & value along with event param and values

Tags: google-bigquery

Requesting your support to fetch specific user property key & value along with event param and  values.

Bigquery table field & value Details (event name, event param key, event param value, user property key, user property value string 
[image]

**Below query is working to fetch  specific event with param key & values.  How to fetch user property key “MemRegDate” & “FreeMember” and its respective values along with below event param.  Requesting your support. Please Help**

```
select 
app_info.id,app_info.version,  
event_date,event_name, 
  param1.value.string_value as category,
  param2.value.string_value as action,
  param3.value.string_value as label,
  count(1) as eventcount
 FROM `<tablet>.events_20190310`,
UNNEST(event_params) as param1,
UNNEST(event_params) as param2,
UNNEST(event_params) as param3
where event_name='BI' and 
param1.key='category' 
and param2.key='action' 
and param3.key='label' 
group by 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6,7
```

I need to report in below Format. Please find below the required query output screenshot
Dimension in Rows

- Event_Name
- Event_param.key Category
- Event_param.key Label
- user_property.key MemRegDate
- user_property.key FreeMember

Values in Columns

Pls. find attached the output screenshot for your kind reference 
[Output Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1G0b.png)

I run the query as it as. Still showing error in the query. Pls find attached the screenshot [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPoYo.png)

Answer (score 0):

Below is a standard Sql example:

```
--Data
WITH data AS (
SELECT 'BI' AS event_name, 
[STRUCT('label' AS key ,'click' AS value), ('action','viewProfile_Sent'), ('category','BI')] AS events,
[STRUCT('MemRegDate' AS key ,'val1' AS value), ('FreeMember','val2'), ('','')] AS user
),
label AS (
SELECT event_name, events.value AS label
FROM data, UNNEST(data.events) as events 
where events.key = 'label'
),
action AS (
SELECT event_name, events.value AS action
FROM data, UNNEST(data.events) as events 
where events.key = 'action'
),
category AS (
SELECT event_name, events.value AS category
FROM data, UNNEST(data.events) as events 
where events.key = 'category'
),
MemRegDate AS (
SELECT event_name, user.value AS value
FROM data, UNNEST(data.user) as user
where user.key = 'MemRegDate'
),
FreeMember AS (
SELECT event_name, user.value AS value
FROM data, UNNEST(data.user) as user
where user.key = 'FreeMember'
)


--Query
SELECT data.event_name, category.category, action.action, label.label,  
MemRegDate.value AS MemRegDate_val, FreeMember.value AS FreeMember_val
from data left join label on data.event_name = label.event_name 
left join action on data.event_name = action.event_name 
left join category on data.event_name = category.event_name 
left join MemRegDate on data.event_name = MemRegDate.event_name 
left join FreeMember on data.event_name = FreeMember.event_name
```

This query produces the following output which is the expected result you placed in your question:

[image]

Comment: @Ramakrishna can you please advise if this helped solved your problem

Comment: Hi Tamir. Thanks for your Support. Is it possible to help wit this. I need the report below dimension in columns

Comment: Not sure i understand. Can you please add to your question the expected results to clarify your need

Comment: HI Tamir. Thanks for the response. Editing my question with output Screenshot. Requesting your support to get the output as mentioned in the screenshot. Dimension in Rows & Values in columns. Pls. check the output screenshot. Pls help Dimension in Rows 
Event_Name
Event_param.key Category
Event_param.key Label
user_property.key MemRegDate
user_property.key FreeMember
Values in Columns.

Comment: Looking at your needed response I cant see why my solution doesn't solve your problem. See the image output I added to my answer. Obviously I left the offset column as an example you can can the query and titles per your need

Comment: Tamir. The output that you mentioned, i cannot correlate category action & label. That is the problem

Comment: Thanks Tamir for the help. But the problem is not solved. Getting below error. Table name "FreeMember" cannot be resolved: dataset name is missing

Comment: I double check and the code in my answer is running with the expected result. Please, double check you are running it as is. Please provide a screenshot with the error and with the query if still not ok

Comment: Tamir: As mentioned attached the error screenshot for your kind reference

Comment: Per your screenshot, you are running only part of my query. My query relay on the data section please COPY ALL the code and run it AS IS. Once ok you will need to modify it to work with your original dataset and tableId